# How to update lenovo ThinkPad from windows 7 to windows 8

Tags: windows-8, thinkpad

I have Lenovo ThinkPad S540 which is already installed Windows 7. But the laptop does not have a DVD player. So I cant install windows 8 using the given CD pack. But when I download Windows 8 updater it either asks me to buy it online or for a product key ( which is not available printed any where).

How can I install Windows 8 in this setup?

Comment: Get an external USB DVD drive, or copy the DVD onto a bootable USB stick via another computer that has a DVD drive.

Comment: Use a USB DVD player.  Create an ISO on another computer and create your own bootable USB drive.  Download an ISO yourself and make a USB drive.  If this is an upgrade license not a system builder disk you can use the installer on windows.com to download and create the USB drive

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a [bootable USB stick](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200124.aspx). You can also use other available methods
2. Copy the DVD content onto the USB
3. During Windows start up, press F12 (or follow on screen instructions) to get the **Boot device** dialog
4. Select USB in the list
5. The process should be the same as when using the original DVD